# Run-time Error 438: Object doesn't support ... for Debug.Print on a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm encountering a error 438 when trying to confirm the expected values of variables.

The error is on line `Debug.Print WBMaster`.  Only the code related to this question is shown.

```
Sub DSMReportsP02()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim DistrictDSM As Range, DistrictsDSMList As Range
Set DistrictsDSMList = Range("E11:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
Dim Period As String, Path As String, DistPeriodFile As String, Territory As String
Dim YYYY As Variant
Dim WBMaster As Workbook, DistMaster As Workbook, CurDstTerrFile As Workbook
Dim wsCount As Integer, x As Integer
Dim wsExists As Boolean
Set WBMaster = ActiveWorkbook
Period = Range("C6").Value
YYYY = Range("C8").Value
wsExists = False

For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList.Cells
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\DSM Master Reports\" & DistrictDSM & ".xlsx"
   Set DistMaster = ActiveWorkbook
   wsCount = Application.Sheets.Count
   Path = "H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\" & DistrictDSM & "\P02"
   DistPeriodFile = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")

Do While DistPeriodFile <> ""
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & DistPeriodFile, UpdateLinks:=False
   DistPeriodFile = Dir
   Set CurDstTerrFile = ActiveWorkbook
   Territory = CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("A3").Value

Debug.Print WBMaster
Debug.Print DistrictDSM
Debug.Print DistMaster
Debug.Print wsCount
Debug.Print Path
Debug.Print DistPeriodFile
Debug.Print CusDstTerrFile
Debug.Print Territory
```

Comment: Is workbook master supposed to be the workbook that houses the code?

Comment: You can't `Debug.Print` an `Object` - `Workbook`, `Range` and so on. But you can `Debug.Print` properties of the object, for example a workbook's `Name`, a Range's `Address`.

Comment: As far as debugging goes, you should qualify your instances of `Range` and this line `For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList.Cells` can just be `For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList`

Comment: Yes.  The wbMaster workbook is the one with the VBA code in it, and is the only workbook open at the time it is wbMaster is set to equal the ActiveWorkbook.  `Set WBMaster = ActiveWorkbook` worked earlier in another section of the code, but I just wanted to confirm it was working here as well.

Comment: I would use `Set WBMaster = ThisWorkbook`. It is more explicit. You should avoid relying on `.Active`

Comment: So to see what the name of the workbook is, would the proper code be `Debug.Print WBMaster.name`?

Comment: Good suggestion re: using ThisWorkbook vs. .Active.

Comment: No, `Debug.Print WBMaster.Name` and `Debug.Print DistrictDSM.Address (False, False)` for ranges. How you set the variables are fine. It is just how you `Print` their properties is what needs to change as suggested by @BigBen

Comment: Sorry, I realized I copied the wrong code earlier.  You beat me to it.  Thanks for confirming the fix!